# Why does the existence of a return type prevent the need for a forward declaration for a parameter?

Tags: c, forward-declaration

Consider a header file **foo.h** that contains:

```
struct wl_display;

struct wl_array * bar(struct wl_display *display);
```

And an implementation file **foo.c** that contains a complete definition of `wl_display` and an implementation of `bar`:

```
struct wl_display {
    int baz;
};

struct wl_array * bar(struct wl_display *display) {
    // ...
}
```

If I remove the forward declaration of `struct wl_display`, from **foo.h**, the *gcc* compiler will:

1. Emit a warning that the occurrence of `struct wl_display *display` in the parameter list is in block scope(*warning: 'struct wl_display' declared inside parameter list* and *warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want*).
2. Emit an error: *conflicting types for 'bar'
   bar(struct wl_display *display)*.

However, if I then add a function that uses struct wl_display* as a return type, such that **foo.h** contains:

```
// struct wl_display;

struct wl_display * foo(void);

struct wl_array * bar(struct wl_display *display);
```

Everything compiles cleanly.

Why does the use of the `struct wl_display*` as a return type remove the need for the forward declaration? What is the "conflict" that causes error #2 above, since the parameter type is just a pointer, and the function signatures are identical?

Comment: Maybe because the function declaration is in file scope? The parameter list is local to the function?

Comment: the `struct wl_display;` defines an *incomplete type*. which is used as an *opaque type* here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any usage of `struct wl_display` in file scope is a forward declaration of the type. So if the compiler sees it first, the usage in the parameter list refers to that type. If the declaration in the list is seen first, this declares a type that is only valid for the list and nowhere else.

Comment: @ybakos: Please start with the difference between using the `struct` itself (where you need the size --> complete type required) or by a pointer, where you don't unless you dereference that pointer.

Comment: @ybakos: It is not. It is exactly the point here. Not noticing that is a good indicator you need to learn more about this subject.

Comment: @Olaf Please educate me, or post an answer. I understand the difference between the use of the incomplete type and the ability to refer freely to a pointer type without the need for forward declaration. I'm asking why _either_ an explicit forward declaration _or_ the use of the same type identifier as a pointer return type makes the compiler happy when seeing a pointer to the incomplete type again in the parameter list of the subsequent function. In other words, how is it that the use of the return type `struct wl_display*` acts the same as an explicit forward declaration `struct wl_display;`.

Comment: Well, you already got the information that the declaration of the pointer **is** a forward declaration of the `struct`. This is due to the C syntax for `struct` (and `union` or `enum` btw.) declarations per se. How about just reading a bit in the standard or a good C book to get the details?

Comment: My last comment on that: The declaration of the function **does** also declare the `struct`! The argument list does **not**.

Answer (score 1):

The first reference to `struct wl_display` constitutes a declaration, albeit an incomplete one.  In the case of a function return type, it is a top-level declaration.  But inside an argument list, it is not.  Instead, when declared inside an argument list, the declaration is scoped within the function, and goes out of scope after the function definition.

Comment: But, a return type is not a forward declaration, is it not?

Comment: The return type can include structure, union, or enum declaration or definition, just as a variable declaration can.

Comment: I'm not asking what valid return types are, rather, I'm asking how a return type that is a struct is interpreted as a forward declaration, when it is not a standalone forward declaration.

Comment: That's exactly what I answered.  It's the same for a function return type or a variable declaration.  If the type introduces a structure, union, or enum type, then it serves as a declaration for that type.